# how to get multiple Events of a single UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using UIBarButtonItem. I want to get it's event in .m file that either, TouchUpInside or TouchDragInside, is performed. Help me.

Answer (score 3):

First add Button to UIBarButtonItem using method if you are creating UIbarButtonItem programmatically

```
initWithCustomView:(UIView *)view
```

If you are using nib file then simply drag button on `UIbarButtonItem` and then get reference outlet of UIButton.

And then  adding target for both event should work.

```
[captureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [captureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpDrag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];


- (void)touchUpInside:(id)sender {

}

- (void)touchUpDrag:(id)sender {

}
```

Here captuteButton is `UIButton`. which is added to `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: Thanks Pawan, I want to do the exactly same thing, I have tried it, it works for UIButton but not for UIBarButton. your captureButton outlet is of type UIButton or UIBarButton?

Comment: Thanks! Pawan ,I have achieved the functionality by making a customView and UIButton. I can't drag RoundRectButton on toolBar, because it only gives only one selector not the list of events. By the way thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try it on loading of your view

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightbarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loginButtonClick:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbarButtonItem;
[rightbarButtonItem release];
```